# Does C programming language has standard libraries that provide data structure like Vocabulary

Tags: c

I want to know if C has libraries (standard only) that provide some vocabulary structure which I can use to add a random string so that it keeps strings in sorted order.

Thanks

Comment: The C standard defines the `qsort()` function which can be used to sort arrays.

Comment: C standard has few container types. You should consider C++

Comment: @Putin - its not totally clear what you are asking. Could you define "vocabulary"? Do you mean "dictionary of words" or "list of words"? Also, how does "sorted order" apply? Do you want a "dictionary of words in sorted order" or a "list of words in sorted order"?

Comment: @jww Well, I actually need structure that preserves sorted order of the list each time I insert random strings of chars. I do not care how it will be implemented...

Answer (score 4):

No, there is no such thing in C.